# The post content just showing up text

Tags: content, the-content

I am newbie in wordpress. I can't fixed it and I really wonder that. I get the content with "the_content()" function. But if I add the picture, just write the attr (alt) of image or when I use link, I can't click because All tags showing up in Paragraph tags (< p>). What am I missing?

> Thanks for helping

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If this has not become link then you have two ways to make it link as follow

1. simply make it link by using `insert/edt link` option from wordpress edit page's `Visula tab`. Select text (`http://ardazaman.com`) and then click on `insert/edt link` option and insert link.
2. By using `Text tab` of wordpress (in which we use to write code), You can make link by putting your url in `anchor tag` like this.

   ```
   Link: <a href="http://ardazaman.com">http://ardazaman.com</a>
   ```

Same procedure for image.

Comment: @Arda Zaman You should give some reply on my answer!